# How to read a file by groups of chars in C?

Tags: c, input, char, realloc

I have a file of a DNA sequence (A's,T's,G's and C's); it has no spaces, commas or line separators. I have to read the first 10,000 values from it and find the two five-value patterns that are repeated the most.

So far I tried to store the different patterns in a simple structure like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* pattern;
    int count;
} pattern;
```

and as I find more new patterns I store them through the following cycle:

```
int size = 10;
int pos = 0; //positions occupied
pattern* patrones = calloc(10, sizeof(pattern));

char temp[6];

FILE* file = fopen("dnaChain.txt", "rb");
while(file != NULL)
{
    bool has = false;
    fgets(temp, 6, file);

    for(int i = 0; i <= pos; i++)
    {
        pattern p = patrones[i];
        char* content = p.pattern;
        int comp = strcmp(content, temp);
        if(comp == 0)
        {
            has = true;
            p.count = p.count+1;
        }
    }

    if(!has)
    {
        pattern new;
        new.pattern = temp;
        new.count = 1;
        if(pos == size-1)
        {
            patrones = realloc(patrones, size+10);
            size += 10;
        }
    else{
        patrones[pos] = new;}
        pos++;
    }
}
```

However my code is wrong and gives me a `segmentation fault` error
when I execute it, please help me out.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread

Comment: Well, we can't give you an answer that introduces you to programming in C. You will have to reach a certain level, and ask questions about specific problems you encounter. We won't be able to help you like this!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's C++ reference, not C. I'd rather pointer OP at `man fread`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That wiki has both C and C++ references, the link is to the C reference.

Comment: ah, sorry, @JohnnyMopp, joachim

Comment: It seems that if you read your characters in groups of five for your initial task then you'll waste too much memory. For example you will need to read `ATTCGATTCG` as `ATTCG`, `TTCGA`, `TCGAT` and so on until second `ATTCG` starting from fifth position. Thus you will need O((n-5)*5) memory. But if you read the whole file into an array and write a proper algo, you do it with O(n) memory.

Comment: @Sergey: I believe this is a test case for KMP algorithm. He could finish the task in O(n) time..

Comment: If the first 10 characters are AGTGCTACTG, do you have 6 or 2 sequences of five characters: AGTGC, GTGCT, TGCTA, GCTAC, CTACT, TACTG or just AGTGC, TACTG?

Comment: @sjsam: The normal [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is for searching for a particular term (sequence of characters) in a longer string, but the problem here is not like that, is it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The problem, of course, is not like that since the pattern is expected as an input. But don't you think the algorithm can be a tweaked a bit to fit the need of the op?

Comment: Not much of an actual modification of kmp. More like doing it multiple times. Assuming you can have any sequence of five, standard searching for each value is still linear anyways (O (5120n))

Comment: @sjsam: Not sure, but there isn't a good option that springs out at me. There are 4^5 aka 1024 possible sequences of 5 letters from the set {A, C, G, T}. You could run KMP 1024 times. I'm not sure that's efficient (actually, I'm sure that's not efficient). The problem can be solved with a single pass over the data and an auxilliary data structure with 1024 entries (linear time, but the space used is exponential in the length of the pattern, so it wouldn't scale well to handling sequences of 10, 20, 100, … characters). OTOH, there are fewer repeats with longer strings; use a sparse hash table?

Comment: I have added the code I'm currently trying, hopefully with this as a starting point hten I can get some guidance and help. thank you., also, I'm aware that wouldn't stop after the first 10⁴ characters, but that's the least of my worries right now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all read *all* 10000 values into memory, then operate only on the in-memory data.

As for finding sequences, it's basically simple sub-string search. A naive solution is to start with the first five characters, and then search for the same substring from the second character, then from the third character, then the fourth and so on. Count the number of times you find the substring.

Then do the same but start with the second character and five characters forward. Look for that substring from the third character, the fourth, and so on.

After the two first searches you will have two counts, one large and one small. If during the next searches you find one substring that has a larger count than either of the current two, then drop the smallest and save the current substring (and its count). And so on until you have checked the whole string.

It will be a lot of loops, and not very effective, but should give you the result you want.

Comment: I was tempted to add after 'And so on until you have checked the whole string' words such as 'ideally making sure you don't check any sequence of five twice (though it will work OK since the second occurrence will have a smaller count than the first occurrence — it would just be a bit wasteful)'.